# Can I use UTILS in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to ask if I can use the following in Oracle:

```
UTILS.CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR2
```

for instance:

```
SELECT insertData,
       UTILS.CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR2(insertData,10,p_style=>104) insert_short  
  FROM students
```

If it is not possible to use `UTILS` package, so which alternative I can use?

Comment: @GoleyTrol .. yes I did and I had problem because of utils .. for that I posted :)

Comment: Oracle does not have built-in `UTILS` package. What are you trying to achieve? Elaborate on that.

Comment: There is no package named 'UTILS' in a default Oracle installation. Either this should be provided by a 3rd party, or you have to use the existing packages or roll your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, yes. My guess is that you've taken some SQL Server T-SQL and run it through the Oracle SQL Developer Translator (**Tools - Migration - Scratch Editor**) and this is what came out the other side. UTILS is a package which SQL Developer will generate for you if you click on the second icon from the left in the scratch editor - it's a brown package tied up with red string by the looks of it.

This generates a bunch of PL/SQL - Search in it for CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR2 (there are several overloads) and there is the code you can use however you want. You will of course also need to familiarise yourself with GET_FORMAT_FROM_STYLE.

<strike>As an aside I can't see how the scratch editor creates the package specification, so you'll need to do this by hand it would seem.</strike>