# Oracle 12c UTILS package not found

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12c on my local host (Win 10) but when I write any procedure or function I am not able to call the `utils` package. I have been using `utils.convert_to_nvarchar2` in 11g on another server and functions compiled successfully. Please can someone advise.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g21o3.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358153/can-i-use-utils-in-oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use UTILS in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358153/can-i-use-utils-in-oracle)

Comment: [Actual code examples are more useful than screenshots](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also it appears that [a search would have found the explanation](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch).

Answer (score 3):

`utils.convert_to_nvarchar2` looks like a user-defined packaged procedure; in other words - as far as I can tell - this isn't a built-in Oracle procedure.

It means that you should acquire its (package's) code from your old 11g database and install it in your new 12c database.